# Python Skipping Rule

Tags: python, python-2.7, rules

I am making this code for a school project and whenever it enters an even number, it is supposed to check if that number is in the list then add 10 to it. instead, it just skips the +10 bit and instead minuses 5 from it. here is the code:

```
import random

print("Lets Play")
play1 = input("Player 1 name?")
play2 = input("Player 2 name?")
print("Hi " + play1 + " & " + play2 + ", let" + "'" + "s roll the dice")

diceNumber = float(random.randint(2,12))
diceNumber2 = float(random.randint(2,12))
diceNumber3 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber4 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber5 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber6 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber7 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber8 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber9 = random.randint(2,12)
diceNumber0 = random.randint(2,12)

print(play1, "Your number is...")
print(diceNumber)
print(play2, "Your number is...")
print(diceNumber2)

evennumber = list = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40]
evennumber = [float(i) for i in list]

if (diceNumber) == (evennumber):
    (diceNumber01) = (diceNumber) + float(10)
else:
    (diceNumber01) = (diceNumber) - float(5)

evennumber = list = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40]
evennumber = [float(i) for i in list]

if (diceNumber2) == (evennumber):
    float(diceNumber2) + float(10)
else:
    float(diceNumber2) - float(5)

print (play1, "Your total points is",diceNumber01,)
print (play2, "Your total points is",diceNumber2,)
```

Comment: You can check if a number is even by checking if there is any reminder if divided by 2:  `if someNumber % 2 == 0:  # it is even else it is odd` - you also do not want to do `evennumber = list = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40]` - that only creates two names for the same data and one of it hides the built-in `list()` function. Use `evennumber = list( range(2,40+1,2) )` instead - it will create a list of numbers ranging from 2 to 40 with a step of 2. I hope you get at least some tutoring on python. I think you can even avoid the list( ... ) around the range() if on py2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a some excess and issues in here, here's a brief summary and some changes.

- Only two dice being used, no need to create 10
- No clear purpose for dice values being `float`
- Can check for `evens` using `if not x % 2`, also if we were to use even list as shown, the only relevant evens are `2 through 12`
- `diceNumber == evennumber` is checking one value to see if it equals and entire list, if used properly would be `if diceNumber in evennumber`
- This statement `float(diceNumber2) + float(10)` assigns the result to nothing

Here is a cleaned up version with some modifications, I recommend using `random.choice` here and just select a random number from a range of numbers so you don't have to randomly generate a new `int` in range everytime, results will be the same.

```
from random import choice

print("Lets Play")
play1 = input("Player 1 name: ")
play2 = input("Player 2 name: ")
print("Hi " + play1 + " & " + play2 + ", let" + "'" + "s roll the dice")

die = list(range(2, 13))

d_1 = choice(die)
print(play1, "Your number is...\n{}".format(d_1))

d_2 = choice(die)
print(play2, "Your number is...\n{}".format(d_2))

if not d_1 % 2:
    d_1 += 10
else:
    d_1 -= 5

if not d_2 % 2:
    d_2 += 10
else:
    d_2 -= 5

print (play1, "Your total points is",d_1)
print (play2, "Your total points is",d_2)
```

> ```
> Lets Play
> Player 1 name: vash
> Player 2 name: stampede
> Hi vash & stampede, let's roll the dice
> vash Your number is...
> 5
> stampede Your number is...
> 2
> vash Your total points is 0
> stampede Your total points is 12
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `in` operator to check if a value is among the values in a list.

Change:

```
if (diceNumber) == (evennumber):
```

to:

```
if (diceNumber) in (evennumber):
```